# Can't get android to connect to the Internet (permission denied)

Tags: android, permissions

Here's my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.bing.com/");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
```

In the manifest, I have this:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>
```

It is outside the application tab, but inside the manifest tag.

And the error I'm getting is this:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)
```

Really not sure why I'm getting this error when I have the internet permission in place. A bit stumped here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shouldn't you have the following?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

(Note the spelling modification between permission and uses-permission)

Comment: Yeah, that did it. I guess I figured my syntax was correct because it didn't throw any warnings or errors in that file. Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes, thanks!

Comment: @Mike - my pleasure - and, you're right, a second set of eyes to spot the 'easy' stuff is what I miss the most when developing alone.